# Pathauto: Custom punctuation replacement

Tags: path-aliases

Instead of having [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) replace punctuation in the path alias with a default separator ( dash for example ), or remove it, can we somehow specify a custom input to replace with?

For example, ***"*** could be replaced with ***inches***

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hook_pathauto_alias_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7).